# How to simulate only stationary AR(1) with φ = 0.9?

Tags: r, time-series, simulation, error, stationarity

I am interesting in simulating AR(1) processes with 0.9 parameter and n = 10. The itterations should be 10000. 
When I was trying to run the program it gave me an error in the estimation procedure.

"Error in arima(newyt, order = c(1, 0, 0)) : 
  non-stationary AR part from CSS "

My code is this:

```
set.seed(1123)
rep<-10000
phix<-0.90
t<-c(NA,rep)
tstar<-c(NA,rep)
tdstar<-c(NA,rep)
r<-c(NA,rep)
cut.est<-c(NA,rep)
cut2.est<-c(NA,rep)
for(i in 1:rep)
{
ts.sim3 <- arima.sim(n = 63, list(ar=c(phix)))
new<-ts(ts.sim3[c(0,14:63)])
cut.ts<-arima(new,order = c(1,0,0))
yt<-arima.sim(n = 63, list(ar=c(phix)))
newyt<-ts(yt[c(0,14:63)])
cut2.ts<-arima(newyt,order = c(1,0,0))
r[i]<-cor(new,newyt)
tstar[i]<-r[i]/(sqrt((((1+(phix*phix))/((1-(phix*phix)))/(50)))))
t[i]<-r[i]/(sqrt((1-r[i]^2)/(50-2)))
cut.est[i]<-coef(cut.ts)["ar1"]
cut2.est[i]<-coef(cut2.ts)["ar1"]
tdstar[i]<-r[i]/(sqrt((((1+(cut.est[i]*cut2.est[i]))/
((1-cut.est[i]*cut2.est[i])))/(50)))))
}
values.t.test<-matrix(t)
mean(cut.est)
mean(cut2.est)
values.t.test
sum(abs(t) > 1.96)
sum(abs(tstar) > 1.96)
sum(abs(tdstar) > 1.96)
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try larger burn-in values. And please do not post additional code which makes so much harder to see where the problem is and which is not related to that particular problem.

Comment: If you simulate such short processes as $n=10$ you will generally not get a stationary process. Especially not if your AR(1) parameter is so large as it will take a few iterations for the process to forget it's previous states. Why do you need to simulate such a short process?

Comment: @mpiktas you are right about the large code, but you were wrong about the burn-in values. I increased the burn-in period but the output was the same.

Comment: @while if you have yearly data then 50 observations are quite valuable. It is very common in econometrics to have small sample size.

Comment: Sorry, I commented prematurely. I didn't realize you were using 50 observations in your code (why did you specify 10 obs in the text?). Anyhow the point still stands. If you try with longer sequences (or a smaller AR(1) parameter) you will not get the error. It doesn't matter how common it is to have small sample sizes in any field, if the samples are too few you will not get a stationary process from your simulation. At least not in all of the 10000 iterations. This is why you get the error.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ML-method, instead of the CSS-ML-method whenever CSS gives a non-stationary AR part. Something like the following:

```
  cut.ts<-try(arima(new,order = c(1,0,0), method="CSS-ML"), silent=TRUE)
  if (class(cut.ts)=="try-error" || cut.ts$code==1)
    cut.ts<-arima(new,order = c(1,0,0), method="ML")
```